# If $(PQN)/N=(QPN)/N$, then $QP=PQ$

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove the title, where P
and Q
are Sylow subgroups of a finite group G
referring to different primes, N
is a minimal normal group and an abelian
p-group, where p
is again distinct from the other primes. G
is solvable.
I know that the hypothesis implies that $PQN=QPN$, and I think I should prove that one between $P$ and $ Q$ is normal, but I'm not be able to do it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please put your question in the body of the post, not in the title.